# Why does the component not re-render after callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the following two components, I expect the EntryList component to re-render after the state changes in the handleEnttryDelete after the button in EntryForm is clicked. Currently the state changes, but the UI isn't updating itself:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

const EntryList = (props) => {
  const [entryList, setEntryList] = useState(props.data);

  const handleEntryDelete = (entry) => {
    const newState = entryList.filter(function (el) {
      return el._id != entry._id;
    });
    setEntryList(() => newState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {entryList.map((entry) => {
        return (
          <EntryForm entry={entry} handleEntryDelete={handleEntryDelete} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const EntryForm = (props) => {
  const [entry, setEntry] = useState(props.entry);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => props.handleEntryDelete(entry)}>
        {entry._id}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EntryList;
```

Comment: Yes, I do. Had corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code probably works, but not as intended. You just have to use `key` while mapping arrays to components.

Therefore, React can distinguish which elements should not be touched during reconciliation when you delete one of the nodes

```
<div>
  {entryList.map((entry) => {
    return <EntryForm key={entry._id} entry={entry} handleEntryDelete={handleEntryDelete} />;
  })}
</div>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but that alone didn't do the trick.

Comment: I have reproduces your example and it does work for me just removes the wrong element due to the key issue i have mentioned

Comment: Thanks for your input! It does work now, but had to restart the app. Seems as the hot-loading feature wasn't working as expected.